# Android Button integer ID

Tags: android, button

I would like to have a function that if called can be passed the name of the button and then change the text of said button. I have attempted to use the function findViewById but it wont let me pass a string as it takes a int. This is my question, how can i store the integer value of the Button id's so i can pass to this function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags if you need to deal with Strings. Set a tag on the Button using the `android:tag` xml attribute or `setTag`. Then you can use `findViewWithTag` to get a reference to the button.

But it'd probably be easier to just use IDs referenced from the resources object `R`: `R.id.button`